# How to delete a Firestore field inside a map that is an array element?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to be able to delete `varToDelete` field inside a map if a condition occurs.

For some reason, the code to delete it is reached, but nothing is happening

Here is the structure of my document:

```
loc [
  {
    var1,
    var2,
    varToDelete
  },
  {
    var1,
    var2,
    varToDelete
  }
]
```

So, I started to think about this code:

```
await db.runTransaction(async (t) => {

  var locRef = db.collection('documents').doc('123-456');
  var locSnapshot = await locRef.get();
  var loc = locSnapshot.data().loc;

  loc.forEach(l => {
    if (typeof l.varToDelete !== 'undefined') {
      t.update(locRef, {
        "varToDelete": admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"varToDelete": admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
```

This will delete a field 'varToDelete' in the document itself. There is not direct method to delete a field from maps in an array. You must read the doc, remove that property from the objects and update the document with the *whole* new 'loc' array.

```js
const newArr = locSnapshot.data().loc.map(({varToDelete, ...rest}) => rest)
t.update(locRef, {loc: newArr})
```

Comment: I did something a bit different based on your suggestion. I need to validate things before deleting the 'varToDelete'. Thanks for your help!